# White Screen after SplashScreen

Tags: ios, angular, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

After starting my App on my device it just loads the preloader and then just shows a white screen. But this only happens on IOS on Android everything works fine.

```
This is the log in Xcode:
2018-11-18 15:38:01.238190+0100 SmartEye[1537:205446] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.5.5 is starting.
2018-11-18 15:38:01.239075+0100 SmartEye[1537:205446] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2018-11-18 15:38:01.249803+0100 SmartEye[1537:205446] CDVWKWebViewEngine: trying to inject XHR polyfill
2018-11-18 15:38:01.305007+0100 SmartEye[1537:205446] CDVWKWebViewEngine will reload WKWebView if required on resume
2018-11-18 15:38:01.305136+0100 SmartEye[1537:205446] Using Ionic WKWebView
2018-11-18 15:38:01.306279+0100 SmartEye[1537:205446] [CDVTimer][console] 0.131011ms
2018-11-18 15:38:01.306450+0100 SmartEye[1537:205446] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.087023ms
2018-11-18 15:38:01.308654+0100 SmartEye[1537:205446] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 2.170086ms
2018-11-18 15:38:01.308774+0100 SmartEye[1537:205446] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.075936ms
2018-11-18 15:38:01.308877+0100 SmartEye[1537:205446] CDVIonicKeyboard: resize mode 1
2018-11-18 15:38:01.309925+0100 SmartEye[1537:205446] [CDVTimer][keyboard] 1.048923ms
2018-11-18 15:38:01.315583+0100 SmartEye[1537:205446] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 5.586028ms
2018-11-18 15:38:01.321968+0100 SmartEye[1537:205446] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 6.287098ms
2018-11-18 15:38:01.322043+0100 SmartEye[1537:205446] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 16.053081ms
2018-11-18 15:38:01.778979+0100 SmartEye[1537:205446] Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 77 ms
```

Maybe it is because I use the ZeroConf Plugin of Cordova but in the Documentation is written that it is compatible with IOS.

Answer (score 0):

update these values in your config.xml file;

```
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1500" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
 <platform name="ios">
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
```

Comment: It is working on Android why should I edit a Preference on Android?

Comment: Thank you will try it out right when I have time :D

Comment: <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="30000" /> 
Change with these.

Comment: And how to do you build your app? `ionic cordova build ios --release` ?

Comment: I build it with ionic cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"

Comment: I also realized that the Plugin ZeroConf (which I use is not loaded)